# Initializing a module with set of defaults (elm or haskell)

Tags: haskell, elm

Let's assume we have a module which is responsible for making api requests to **Flickr**. I don't want to hard code api keys into Flickr module. Api key could be get by an ajax request.

For now every function in the Flickr module accept apiKey as its argument. But its not that cool pass that api key all around. Is there any simple way to solve that? Or is it possible to share some values between modules without passing that every single function.

```
module Flickr where

searchPhotos : String -> String -> ...
searchPhotos apiKey query = ...

getPhotoInfo : String -> String -> ...
getPhotoInfo apiKey photoId = ...

anotherOne : String -> ...
anotherOne apiKey = ...
```

---

**UPDATE:** What i have tried so far is partially applying functions. I put apiKey like arguments at the end. But now I have to pass that function all around, any other ideas?

```
makeFlickrRequest : (String -> String -> a) -> a
makeFlickrRequest flickrMethod = flickrMethod "myApikey" "mySecret"

photosSearch : String -> String -> String -> ...
photosSearch query apiKey secret =
    makeHTTPCallhere ...

-- Usage:
makeFlickrRequest (photosSearch "haskell")
```

Comment: This sounds like a use case for the [`reader monad`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/mtl-1.1.0.1/docs/Control-Monad-Reader.html).

Comment: you can partialy apply the apikey for all your functions, is this what you need?

Comment: @DanielSanchez actually I tried that (updated question). But now i have to pass makeFlickrRequest function to every module who needs to make a request. Im looking for a better option :)

Comment: make `'` version of this functions, im not a pro haskeller im just saying whatever cames to my head, maybe the reader monad as sayed is an easyer aproach.

Comment: Another good way to pass configuration info around implicitly is to use the `reflection` library. You `reify` the configuration when calling whatever function gets things going for real, and then use `reflect` to get it back wherever you need it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Frerich Raabe's solution works great for Haskell but we unfortunately don't have the luxury of `do` notation in Elm or a Reader Monad equivalent.

However, we have ports, which we can use to provide configuration data when initializing the Elm module from Javascript.

For instance, you can have a port called `apiKey` defined in Elm. Since the value of the port comes from javascript, we only define the function signature, not the body:

```elm
port apiKey : String
```

In the HTML/javascript file where the Elm module gets initiated, you can pass a second parameter that contains initial port values like this:

```html
<script>
  var app = Elm.fullscreen(Elm.Main, {
    apiKey: "myApiKey"
  });
</script>
```

Now, throughout your Elm code, you have a constant function called `apiKey` always available. You never need to pass it in as a parameter to other functions.

Answer (score 6):

With the [reader monad](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/mtl-1.1.0.1/docs/Control-Monad-Reader.html), you can hide the common 'environment' of all your functions (the API key) away. Here's a simple example:

First,

```
import Control.Monad.Reader
```

Then, some type aliases to help readability. What's noteworthy here is the `FlickrRequest a` part - it represents a flickr request which returns a value of type `a`:

```
type APIKey = String
type Photo = String
type PhotoInfo = String

type FlickrRequest a = Reader APIKey a
```

Here are two dummy implementations of searching for photos and getting the information for some photo:

```
searchPhotos :: String -> FlickrRequest [Photo]
searchPhotos query = do
    apiKey <- ask
    return ["<Photo for query " ++ query ++ " (api key " ++ apiKey ++ ")>"]

getPhotoInfo :: Photo -> FlickrRequest PhotoInfo
getPhotoInfo photo = do
    apiKey <- ask
    return $ "This is the photo information for photo " ++ photo ++ " (" ++ apiKey ++ ")"
```

Note that the API key is passed implicitly via the `FlickrRequest` reader. Within the functions, you can access that environment (you get 'read' the environment) using [`ask`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/mtl-1.1.0.1/docs/Control-Monad-Reader-Class.html#v:ask). The beauty of this comes in when combining such functions which all operate in the same environment, e.g.:

```
-- This could be just `searchPhotos "*" >>= mapM getPhotoInfo` but I don't
-- want to obscure things unnecessarily.
allPhotoInfos :: FlickrRequest [PhotoInfo]
allPhotoInfos = do
    photos <- searchPhotos "*"
    sequence (map getPhotoInfo photos)
```

We first call `searchPhotos` and then apply `getPhotoInfo` to all the found photos. Notice how the API key is nowhere to be seen, it's implicitely passed around!

Finally, to run the whole thing, you can use the `runReader` function. Something like

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
    let myAPIKey = "someAPIKey"
    print (runReader allPhotoInfos myAPIKey)
```

Comment: Beautiful and elegant, must get myself onto monads, thanks for this.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. I was trying to avoid using monads to keep it simple. But it seems the easiest way to handle that is using reader monad. Elm doesn't have ```do``` notaion unfortunately :( I will accept your answer if someone doesn't come up with alternative solution.

Answer (score 0):

Just for explaining my comments, I mean apply the apikey to every function as this [example](http://goo.gl/uEdKki):

```
type ApiKey = String

apikey::ApiKey
apikey = "foo"


f1 :: ApiKey -> String -> String
f1 "foo" _  = "1"
f1 _ s =  s

f2 :: ApiKey -> String -> String
f2 "foo" _  = "2"
f2 _ s =  s

f1', f2':: (String -> String)
[f1', f2'] = map (\x-> x apikey) [f1, f2]

main = do
    putStrLn $ f1 "asdf" "2"
    putStrLn $ f1' "2"
```